# How to replace a string in the table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `LIST`, can anyone please tell me how to replace all the data under the table LIST In sql server

Comment: can you describe more your question....

Comment: You will need to be a bit more specific in what you are after. What exactly is it you want to do? What have you tried so far? What are you unable to find out?

Comment: Please provide more details, a table can contain many columns, do you want to replace data in one column or all the columns? what string you want to replace and with which string?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace string in SQL table by following command

```
Update <tablename> SET <columnname> = '<newstring>'
```

If you have any condition you can add following line after above line

```
where <condition>
```

Condition can be something like

```
columnname = 'sometext'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    LIST
SET
    COLUMN1    =    'SOMETHING BESIDES WHAT IS CURRENTLY IN COLUMN1'
```